# Ошибка Процедура или функция с указанным именем не определена

Tags: 1с

В конфигурации сделал подписку на событие при записи справочника.
В общем модуле создал процедуру:

```
Процедура СправочникОбъектПриЗаписи(Источник, Отказ, СтандартнаяОбработка = Истина) Экспорт
    ЗапросМенеджеров = Новый Запрос;
    ЗапросМенеджеров.УстановитьПараметр("Группа_Менеджеров","Менеджеры АИ");
    ТекстЗапроса = "ВЫБРАТЬ
                    |ГруппыПользователейПользователиГруппы.Пользователь.Наименование КАК ФИО,
                    |ГруппыПользователей.Наименование
                    |ИЗ
                    |Справочник.ГруппыПользователей.ПользователиГруппы КАК ГруппыПользователейПользователиГруппы
                    |ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Справочник.ГруппыПользователей КАК ГруппыПользователей
                    |ПО ГруппыПользователейПользователиГруппы.Ссылка = ГруппыПользователей.Ссылка
                    |ГДЕ
                    |ГруппыПользователей.Наименование = &Группа_Менеджеров";
    ЗапросМенеджеров.Текст = ТекстЗапроса;
    Менеджеры = ЗапросМенеджеров.Выполнить().Выбрать();
    Пока Менеджеры.Следующий() Цикл
        Если (Строка(глЗначениеПеременной("глТекущийПользователь")) = Строка(Менеджеры.ФИО)) И
                    Строка(Источник.Метаданные().Имя) = "Номенклатура" Тогда
            СтандартнаяОбработка = Ложь;
            Предупреждение("Вам запрещено вносить изменения в данный справочник!",,"Ошибка!");
            Отказ = Истина;
        КонецЕсли;
    КонецЦикла;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Конфигурация обновляется нормально, а вот при запуске на отладку возникает ошибка:

> {ОбщийМодуль.ОбщегоНазначения.Модуль(8833,4)}: Процедура или функция с
>   указанным именем не определена (Предупреждение)
>             <>Предупреждение("Вам запрещено вносить изменения в данный
>   справочник!","Ошибка!");

Помогите разобраться, ведь `Предупреждение` является встроенной в язык, так в чем же дело?

Comment: 1. почему вы не используте права?
2. почему проверка идет при записи, а не ПередЗаписью? Все проверки должны быть до записи объекта в базу, а вы проверяете уже после того как занесли объект (правда еще не завершили транзакцию).  

ЗЫ Предупреждение F1 - не доступен на сервере.

Comment: Yura Ivanov, это все ради интереса и обучения, поэтому как бы все равно При- или ПредЗаписью, как-то так :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Процедура СправочникОбъектПриЗаписи выполняется на сервере не так ли ? Процедура Предупреждение работает только на клиенте

Comment: Уважаемый renegator, спасибо огромное!!!!